# UIButton hit area is too big

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uibutton, ios7

In my application all UIButton objects are behaving strangely. It seems that the hit area is twice as big. So when I click on a button I'm actually clicking on the button next or below it.

I have created the buttons programmatically as well as with Interface Builder, but both with the same result.

In my application I'm using a theme proxy. But even if I disable it the buttons are still behaving strangely.

Here's is the code for creating the button:

```
    _btOpenContact = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _btOpenContact.frame = Rect(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) - 200, 100, 100);
    [_btOpenContact addTarget:self action:@selector(navigateToContact) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    _btOpenContact.backgroundColor = RGB(233, 12, 24); resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 3, 0)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:_btOpenContact];
```

Anyone got any ideas what I'm doing wrong??? Thanks in advance

**update**

I added a breakpoint to one of the button:

```
    <UIButton: 0x1e0a1220; frame = (0 348; 100 100); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e0a11e0>>
```

And the CALayer inside of it:

```
    <CALayer:0x1e0a11e0; position = CGPoint (50 398); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 100 100); delegate = <UIButton: 0x1e0a1220; frame = (0 348; 100 100); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e0a11e0>>; backgroundColor = <CGColor 0x1e0a1300> [<CGColorSpace 0x1d53db80> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)] ( 0.913725 0.0470588 0.0941176 1 )>
```

Comment: _btOpenContact.frame..?

Comment: O sorry... I have some macros in my project. Rect is actually CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)

Comment: can u add a screenshot of this

Comment: @manujmv I upload some screens: [help.png](http://im3d.nl/screens/help.png) [menu.png](http://im3d.nl/screens/menu.png)

Comment: There should some problem with code, buttons don't behave the way you have described. You have to double check the code. And, by the way, how about the background image you put to the button, is it stretched, scaled or anything like that?

Comment: @Fahri Azimov I will check my code (I did it actually a couple of times already, before posting my question). Regarding the background image, I also had tested it with a background image, just a solid color. But the buttons still are behaving the same.

Comment: try like this sub class a view and add the button there ......

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368120/smaller-active-area-for-custom-uibarbuttonitem

Comment: In the end I subclassed UIButton and overwritten the hitTest method to check if I'm really clicking the button. (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I still have no idea what's causing this bug. (maybe a bug in the iOS7 sdk...?) I fixed it by subclassing UIButton and doing a hit test to check if I'm really clicking the button.

```
    #import "TTButton.h"

    @implementation TTButton {}

    - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint([self bounds], point)) {
            NSLog(@"inside");
            return self;
        }

        return nil;
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You have to change image size used in uibutton, button hit area is under uibutton frame but image size is small then button frame.

Comment: Even if I'm not using an image, the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You have set width of your button to be 320 means it will cover whole screen, change your width and height to 100 * 100 and set any background color for testing. You'll get the idea what is the visible area of your button by seeing the background color of it.

Comment: Tried it, but still having the same problem. I updated my question with the new (testing) code

Comment: And the visible area and click area are not same?

Comment: Sadly not..... The click area is bigger. But now I also notice that the clickarea is twice as big as the button itself